# CGContextMoveToPoint before CGContextShowText call

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

Does CGContextMoveToPoint work with CGContextShowText?  I'm trying to draw to a PDF.  Without any translating of the CTM, if I draw text, I see it in the bottom left side of the screen.  Then I try to move to point (100,100), and the text is still there.  But if I translate the CTM to position 100, 100, then I see the text at that point.  Does CGContextMoveToPoint work with CGContextShowText?  Otherwise it seems like I translate my CTM, then I need to make the reverse translation, then move it somewhere else to draw other text (like if I were doing a title, and then starting a paragraph).  Thanks!

Comment: Although this doesn't answer my question, I see that there is CGContextShowTextAtPosition that I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  CGContextSetTextPosition() instead. I don't know why Quartz keeps different positions for text and graphics, but that's the way it is.